# Android-EditText Border is not visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a border around a EditText  but it does not work
Here is my EditText code

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:autofillHints="no"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
    android:hint="@string/text"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColorHint="#757575" />
```

Here is my .xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:color="@color/border"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Edit: I tried adding solid color but the whole box became of that color and not just border.
the corners are fixed

Comment: Did you tried to add android:width in stroke tags?

Comment: should we remove the solid and then try that

Comment: try something like: `<stroke android:color="@color/border" android:width="5dp"/>`

Comment: Thnks!It worked

Comment: I removed the solid and then set the width to elevation

Comment: If you just want to create a border around the EditText, you can remove solid tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the width on stroke tags.

This should work:

```
<stroke android:color="@color/border" android:width="5dp"/>
```